# Is this shadow file normal or hacked?

Tags: passwd-file

I may have been hacked.  This is most of my `/etc/shadow` file.  I can't understand why so may items have a password hash of "x".  Does "x" have a special meaning?  Or is it really a hashed password, one that is extra, extra short, like I suppose a hacker might use?

```
daemon:x:15910:0:99999:7:::  
bin:x:15910:0:99999:7:::  
sys:x:15910:0:99999:7:::  
sync:x:15910:0:99999:7:::  
games:x:15910:0:99999:7:::  
man:x:15910:0:99999:7:::  
lp:x:15910:0:99999:7:::  
mail:x:15910:0:99999:7:::  
news:x:15910:0:99999:7:::  
uucp:x:15910:0:99999:7:::  
proxy:x:15910:0:99999:7:::  
www-data:!x:15910:0:99999:7:::  
backup:x:15910:0:99999:7:::  
list:x:15910:0:99999:7:::  
irc:x:15910:0:99999:7:::  
gnats:x:15910:0:99999:7:::  
nobody:x:15910:0:99999:7:::  
libuuid:x:15910:0:99999:7:::  
bind:*:15910:0:99999:7:::  
fetchmail:*:15910:0:99999:7:::  
sshd:*:15910:0:99999:7:::  
syslog:*:15910:0:99999:7:::  
klog:*:15910:0:99999:7:::  
smmta:*:15910:0:99999:7:::  
smmsp:*:15910:0:99999:7:::  
mysql:!:15916:0:99999:7:::  
messagebus:*:15940:0:99999:7:::  
usbmux:*:15940:0:99999:7:::
```

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It is not X, it is *.

As mentioned in the man page, that character means the user do not need to login:

> If the password field contains some string that is not a valid result of crypt(3), for instance ! or *, the user will not be
>              able to use a unix password to log in (but the user may log in the system by other means).

For more info :

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcshadow-file/

http://linux.die.net/man/5/shadow

Comment: It is `x` in a lot of fields. Anything that is not a valid hash can stay there to say the user will not login. See the `daemon` entry for example --- it most go with the tastes of the specifically utility or developer who wrote it.

Comment: @Rmano I don't think it make sense. Perhaps because of difference of Linux distributions showing.